# Alice and Bob are safety inspectors

Tags: probability

Alice and Bob are safety inspectors. 
They classify elevators as follows: $1$ is unsafe, $2$ is safe and minor repair work is needed and $3$ is safe and no repair work is needed.  
Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the classification given by respectively Alice and Bob.  
The joint probability mass function of their classifications is given by $$p(x,y)=\cases{K(x+y)& if $x, y\in \{1, 2, 3\}$\\0 & otherwise}$$where $K$ is a constant.

a) Determine $K$. 
b) Compute the probability that an elevator is classified as safe by both Alice and Bob. 
c) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent random variables?

Can someone help me with this exercise, I have no clue how to solve part a) (determine $K$), then I think that I can solve the other two question without problem. I think that I should create a table with the join and marginal distribution, is the correct way?

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& 1 & 2 & 3 &  \\ \hline
 1& K(1+1) & K(1+2) & K(1+3) &\\ \hline
 2&  K(2+1) & K(2+2) & K(2+3) &\\ \hline
 3&  K(3+1) & K(2+3) & K(3+3)& \\ \hline
 &  & & & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}

But then how can I solve for K?

Comment: For a), it will help to think about what we require of a probability mass function in order to call it a "probability mass function"

Comment: Creating the tables sounds like the right way to go, once you have solved for $K.$

Comment: How then can I solve for K?

Comment: How often does each $x+y = 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ occur?

Comment: 1/3 mhh I don't know..

Comment: @FabioTaccaliti Your joint distribution is right. Now sum up all cells of the table and set it equal to 1. Then solve for $K$. Edit: [BruceET](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/221800/bruceet) has posted right now an answer which gives you useful hints for (b) and (c) as well.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is a good start. I will try to help you finish this. Take the next step with your table:

```
x \ y     1    2    3     Total
--------------------------------
1        2K   3K   4K       9K
2        3K   4K   5K      12K
3        4K   5K   6K      15K
--------------------------------
Total    9K  12K  15K      36K = 1
```

(a) So $K = 1/36.$

(b) Which of the nine cells correspond to "Declared safe by both Alice and Bob"? Add their probabilities.

(c) $P(X=1, Y=1) = 2K = 2/36.$

Also, $P(X=1) = P(Y = 1) = 9/36.$

Does $P(X=1, Y=1) = P(X=1)\times P(Y=1),$ as required by independence?

Comment: Thank you very much, now everything is clear!